# Is it safe to delete the content of ~/Library/Logs?

Tags: macos, storage, logs

I would like to know if it is safe to delete the content of my ~/Library/Logs folder, because it is taking quite a lot of space.

I've found that it should be saved, but would be nice if there is someone who can confirm it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, log files can be safely deleted. Next time a log file needs to be appended to and is missing, it will be created (don't delete the actual Logs folder itself though). Log files are always presumed transient. However, before you delete all your log files, it might be worth keeping the most recent content of the most important log files in case you need to troubleshoot any problems.