# Can I delete files in /Library/Containers/com.apple.mail/Data/Library/Logs?

Tags: mail.app, storage

My MacBook is becoming unstable due to limited disk space the major culprit for which is a mysterious category called "Other". Poking around a bit (a lot actually) I find that I have over 650 GB of Other, 330 GB of which is in a single file in

```
~/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail/Data/Library/Logs/Mail
```

called

```
imap-mail.outlook.com-<GUID>.txt
```

What is this file? Is it safe to delete it?

Comment: I can't tell you if it is safe to delete nor what this file exactly is. If your system is backed up, I would just try to delete it and see what happens. No file should be this large, especially not a .txt file from the apple mail client.

Comment: @X_841Giving that a try!

Comment: In general deleting a log file shouldn't do any harm other than you/a specialist later on might not be able to troubleshoot issues that you had previous to deleting the file. This post also talks about deleting log files in general: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/272929/is-it-safe-to-delete-the-content-of-library-logs?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply delete the file. It's even safe to do this while Mail is running.

Accumulation of these files [can be prevented](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/389248/4395) by choosing *Window > Connection Doctor* in Mail and making sure "Log Connection Activity" is unchecked.